# How can I convert Javascript code sample into Unityscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a one .**jslib** formatted JS code in the **Plugins** folder.

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, { 
CheckForPermission : function (){
    if (typeof(DeviceOrientationEvent) !== "undefined" && typeof(DeviceOrientationEvent).requestPermission === 'function')
    {
        DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission().then(response => {
            if (response === 'granted') {
                window.alert("granted 1");
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            window.alert(error);
        });
    } else {
        window.alert("granted 2");
    };
},})
```

When I want to build my project it gives error [screenshot][1]

Do you have any ideas?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6TlR.png

Comment: UnityScript is deprecated long time ago. Unity now support only C#

Comment: yes, but when I tried write simple window.alert(); function it works. (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

Comment: Don't use `=>`, it's not supported by unity.

Comment: @shingo how can I convert this code to no lambda version. I don't have a js knowledge

Comment: JavaScript is pretty easy to read and google will answer questions.

Comment: @shingo what do you mean `Don't use =>, it's not supported by unity` ..? It is literally in their [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html) and this has nothing to do really with what Unity supports .. JavaScript is called browser side and only invoked by Unity or the other way round ...

Comment: @JamwitKarimov I don't see the point for `unityscript` here .. do you want to run this browser side in the JavaScript of your web page or do you actually rather want to run this within Unity itself?

Comment: @JamwitKarimov try to replace `response =>` with `function (response)`

Comment: @derHugo please distinguish between JavaScript and Unity's JavaScript Plugin

Comment: @derHugo I need to run from the Unity